# Show self-adjointness with eigenvalue expansion.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory

I was wondering if anybody here knows how to show that the negative Laplacian is self-adjoint on the 2 nd order Sobolev space of the two-sphere? I read that it is a rather cumbersome calculation, but I also don't see how one should start doing this calculation, so if you have a good reference for this or if you like to give a proof here, this would totally answer my question.

Comment: Please define $H^2$.

Comment: Do you know about the spherical harmonics and how they relate to the Laplacian on the sphere?

Comment: I think that one way to do this is to show that $\Delta$ is symmetric on $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}$ on this manifold, which follows from having no boundary (you can artificially introduce a great circle and split the integrals.) Then you argue that the form $(-\Delta f,f)+(f,f)$ closes to the Sobolev space $H^{1}(M)$. Finally, show that the Friedrichs extension--which is designed to be selfadjoint--is the same as the closure of your operator because of how $(-\Delta f,f)=(\nabla f,\nabla f)$. Can you show that the closure of the graph of $\Delta$ gives you the Sobolev space?

Comment: @XinWang : Spherical harmonics give you a complete orthonormal basis of eigenfunctions for the Laplacian on the sphere. If $A$ is symmetric and $Ae_{n}=\lambda_{n}e_{n}$ for a complete orthonormal basis $\{ e_{n} \}$, then $A$ is sefadjoint on the domain consisting of $x$ for which $\sum_{n}|\lambda_{n}|^{2}|(x,e_{n})|^{2} < \infty$.

Comment: @XinWang : The $H^{2}$ norm is $\|f\|_{H^{2}}^{2}=\|\Delta f\|^{2}+\|f\|^{2}$, which is the graph norm of $\Delta$. So the condition that $f \in L^{2}$ must satisfy $\|\Delta f\|^{2}=\sum_{n}|\lambda_{n}|^{2}|(f,e_{n})|^{2} < \infty$ is equivalent to the condition that $f \in H^{2}$. The spherical harmonics $\{ e_{n} \}$ span all of $L^{2}$, but the added conditions define $H^{2}$. The $\{ e_{n} \}$ are an orthogonal basis of $H^{2}$ as well; they require different normalization to be orthonormal in $H^{2}$, but that's an expected technicality.

Comment: @XinWang : When you learned about the spherical harmonics, did you learn that they were mutually orthogonal? Once you know that, then $(e_{n},e_{m})_{H^{2}}=(e_{n},e_{m})+(\Delta e_{n},\Delta e_{m})=(e_{n},e_{m})+\lambda_{n}\lambda_{m}(e_{n},e_{m})=0$ if $n\ne m$.

Comment: @XinWang : Yes. A vector $y$ is in the domain of the adjoint $(T+S)^{\star}$ iff $x\mapsto ((T+S)x,y)$ is a bounded linear functional. If $S$ is bounded, then $y$ is in the domain of the adjoint of $T$ iff it is in the domain of the adjoint of $T+S$. So the adjoint domain and operator domain remain equal; because $T+S$ is symmetric on that domain, then it selfadjoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your remarks, you asked about two specific issues.

**Question 1**: Why is the closure of $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}(S)$ under the graph norm of the Laplacian the same as $H^{2}(S)$, even though the first derivative terms are not present in this norm $\|f\|+\|\Delta f\|$?

The Laplacian in spherical coordinates is
$$
\frac{1}{r^{2}}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}r^{2}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}
   + \frac{1}{r^{2}\sin\theta}\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\sin\theta\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}
   + \frac{1}{r^{2}\sin^{2}\theta}\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial\phi^{2}},
$$
and the restriction of this operator to functions at $r=1$ which do not depend on $r$ is the correct Laplacian $\Delta_{S}$ on the spherical manifold for the unit sphere $S$:
$$
         \Delta_{S} = \frac{1}{\sin\theta}\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\sin\theta\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}
   + \frac{1}{\sin^{2}\theta}\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial\phi^{2}}.
$$

The Sobolev norm that I gave you on the sphere does not require the first derivatives because the manifold has no boundary. Assuming $f$ is in $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}(S)$,
and noting that $dS=\sin\theta\,d\theta\,d\phi$, integration by parts gives
$$
     (-\Delta_{S}f,f) = \|\nabla f\|^{2} = \int_{S}\left(\left|\frac{\partial f}{\partial\theta}\right|^{2}+\left|\frac{1}{\sin\theta}\frac{\partial f}{\partial\phi}\right|^{2}\right)dS
$$
This happens because of working on a manifold without boundary, where there are no boundary evaluation terms after integrating by parts. This requires an argument, but can easily be achieved by splitting along a closed curve such as a great circle.

Therefore, when you consider the closure of the graph of $-\Delta_{S}$ from the $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}(S)$ functions, you see that no explicit mention of first derivatives is needed because the following is continuous with respect to the graph norm of $-\Delta_{S}$:
$$   (f,f)+(-\Delta_{S}f,f)=\|f\|_{H^{1}}^{2}. $$
This is the expected case for the typical compact manifold without boundary.

**Question 2:** I'll modify this question a bit, and get back to yours below. Let $\{ e_{n} \}$ be an orthonormal basis of a Hilbert space $X$ and let $\{ \lambda_{n} \}$ be a sequence of real numbers. Then why is $Ax = \sum_{n}\lambda_{n}(x,e_{n})e_{n}$ selfadjoint on the domain $\mathcal{D}(A)=\{ x : \sum_{n}\lambda_{n}^{2}|(x,e_{n})|^{2} < \infty \}$?

It is easy to verify that $(Ax,y)=(x,Ay)$ for $x,y\in\mathcal{D}(A)$. Next it is shown that $A\pm iI$ are surjective. To do this, let $y\in X$ be given, and define
$$
              x_{\pm} = \sum_{n}\frac{1}{\lambda_{n}\pm i}(y,e_{n})e_{n}
$$
This is well-defined because the scalar coefficients are uniformly bounded by $1$. And $(x_{\pm},e_{n})=(y,e_{n})/(\lambda_{n}\pm i)$ for all $n$. Hence,
$$
\begin{align}
        \sum_{n}|\lambda_{n}(x_{\pm},e_{n})|^{2} & =\sum_{n} \left|\frac{\lambda_{n}}{\lambda_{n}\pm i}\right|^{2}|(y,e_{n})|^{2} \\
      & = \sum_{n}\frac{\lambda_{n}^{2}}{\lambda_{n}^{2}+1}|(y,e_{n})|^{2} \le \|y\|^{2}
\end{align}
$$
Therefore $x_{\pm} \in \mathcal{D}(A)$ and, and one can check that
$$
          (A\pm iI)x_{\pm} = y.
$$
This is enough to imply that the symmetric operator $A$ is selfadjoint. First, the domain is dense because it includes all finite linear combinations of $\{ e_{n}\}$. So the adjoint $A^{\star}$ is well-defined with $\mathcal{D}(A)\subseteq\mathcal{D}(A^{\star})$ because of the symmetry of $A$.

To show that $A$ is selfadjoint, we suppose $z \in \mathcal{D}(A^{\star})$ and show that $z \in \mathcal{D}(A)$. For such $z$,
$$
         ((A-iI)x,z) = (x,(A^{\star}+iI)z),\;\;\; x\in\mathcal{D}(A).
$$
Because $A+iI$ is surjective, there exists $x'\in\mathcal{D}(A)$ such that
$$
           (A^{\star}+iI)z = (A+iI)x'.
$$
Now the above gives
$$
         ((A-iI)x,z)=(x,(A+iI)x')=((A-iI)x,x').
$$
(The second equality follows from symmetry of $A$ on its domain.) Therefore,
$z-x'$ is orthogonal to $(A-iI)\mathcal{D}(A)=X$, which gives $z=x'\in\mathcal{D}(A)$. So $A^{\star}=A$.

**Original Question 2:** Suppose $A$ is symmetric on its domain with a complete orthonormal basis of eigenvectors $\{ e_{n}\}$ with eigenvalues $\{\lambda_{n}\}$. Why is $A$ selfadjoint on the domain as described in Question 1?

I should have said that the *closure* $A^{c}$ of $A$ is selfadjoint on this domain. If $A$ is already closed, then $A$ itself is selfadjoint. This is a technicality that does not change anything because a densely defined symmetric $A$ is always closable to a symmetric $A^{c}$, a fact which is easily checked from the symmetry relation. And this $A$ is densely defined because of the complete orthonormal basis of eigenfunctions.

To see that $x$ in the proposed domain is in the domain of $A^{c}$, first note that $x_{k}=\sum_{n=1}^{k}(x,e_{n})e_{n}$ is in the domain of $A$ and $Ax_{k}=\sum_{n=1}^{k}(x,e_{n})\lambda_{n}e_{n}$. By definition of this domain, $x_{k}$ converges to $x$ and $Ax_{k}$ converges to $y=\sum_{n}\lambda_{n}(x,e_{n})e_{n}$ which puts $\langle x,y\rangle$ in the graph of the closure $A^{c}$ with $A^{c}x=y$ as proposed. By what was shown before, this definition of $A$ is selfadjoint.

Let $A_{\mbox{new}}$ be the definition given using the orthonormal basis. In terms of graph inclusions,
$$
                      A_{\mbox{new}} \preceq A^{c} \preceq (A^{c})^{\star}.
$$
The first inclusion was just shown, and the second follows from symmetry of $A^{c}$. Therefore, taking adjoints, and recalling that $(A^{c})^{\star\star}=A^{c}$ because $A^{c}$ is closed, you get
$$
              A^{c} \preceq (A^{c})^{\star} \preceq A_{\mbox{new}}^{\star}=A_{\mbox{new}}
$$
Putting those two chains together forces $A^{c} = A_{\mbox{new}}$ to be selfadjoint and equal to the nice new operator $A_{\mbox{new}}$.

Comment: @XinWang : Yes, these are equivalent norms, which makes dealing with the closure of $\Delta$ the same as closing in the Sobolev norm.